# Select Case / Update one field based on another

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically, I am trying to cleanse a database and have all file paths point to sample documents.  I am reading from one column (extension), and then updating another column (filename) and making a change based on the extension.  I also want a catch all.  For example, if extension is DOC, then make the path "sample.doc"; if the extension is PDF, then make the path "sample.pdf", if unknown, then make the path "sample.txt".

I have this code working, but think it would be better served with a select/case loop:

```
select * from dbo.tsrecelec
UPDATE dbo.TSRECELEC
SET dbo.tsrecelec.reSID = '00+SampleWord.doc'
WHERE dbo.tsrecelec.reExtension = 'DOC'
UPDATE dbo.TSRECELEC
SET dbo.tsrecelec.reSID = '00+SampleWord.docx'
WHERE dbo.tsrecelec.reExtension = 'DOCX'
UPDATE dbo.TSRECELEC
SET dbo.tsrecelec.reSID = '00+SampleADOBE.pdf'
WHERE dbo.tsrecelec.reExtension = 'PDF'
```

In my NONE SQL brain, I was thinking something like this might work?

```
SELECT reSID, reExtension,
    CASE
        WHEN reExtension = 'DOC' THEN  SET reSID = '00+SampleWord.doc'
        WHEN dbo.tsrecelec.reExtension = 'DOCX' THEN SET             dbo.tsrecelec.reSID = '00+SampleWord.docx'
        ELSE dbo.tsrecelec.reSID = '00+SampleFile.txt'
END
FROM dbo.tsrecelec;
```

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: You are close. Just need to Bring out SET reSID out and then use the CASE method. Something like SET reSID = CASE WHEN 1 THEN 1 WHEN 2 THEN 2..... END

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `CASE...WHEN...THEN...`. It's more performant if you are getting more extensions in the future:

```
UPDATE yourtable
    SET col1 = (CASE WHEN col2 = 'extension you want'
                      THEN 'nameofyourfile.extension'
                      WHEN ...
                      THEN ...
                 END)
    WHERE col2 IN ('extension1', 'extension2', 'extension3','...');
```

Comment: Thank you both for the answer.. worked great... Followup questions:  
1) Do I have to list all possible extensions to be found in the "IN" section?
2) How do I have a catch-all, if there is an extension I am not aware of, then simply put a generic file, Sample.txt?  In my mind that would be similar to an ELSE condition..
3) Thanks again.

Comment: You can create a stored procedure with extension in parameter as input (PL/SQL) and see the exception documentation here : http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-error-handling-in-stored-procedures/

Answer (score 1):

Three updates is fine, but you can phrase this as:

```
UPDATE dbo.TSRECELEC
    SET reSID = (CASE WHEN reExtension = 'DOC'
                      THEN '00+SampleWord.doc'
                      WHEN reExtension = 'DOCX'
                      THEN '00+SampleWord.docx'
                      WHEN reExtension = 'PDF'
                      THEN '00+SampleADOBE.pdf'
                 END)
    WHERE reExtension IN ('DOC', 'DOCX, 'PDF');
```